# Ionic3 splash screen and icon - No platfrom detected

Tags: ionic-framework

Let me first say. Each time i run

```
ionic cordova build android --dev
```

It first run this command

```
cordova platform add android
```

At the start of the project I already added the android platform successfully. So I dont know why on every build it has to add android platform again. But each build works perfectly well on my phone. Then yesterday when I tried to run

```
ionic cordova resources
```

and it says

```
no platform detected. Please run ionic cordova platfrom add
```

Please help

Comment: have you installed the android SDK separately rather than using cordova platform add android

Comment: maybe Your installation is not completed,sometime its  corrupt try to install again node and reinstall ionic and cordova